# New Ubuntu Installation Freezing

Tags: firefox, 15.10, freeze, crash, browser

**Warning, I'm new here**

I've just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on an empty drive. I have another drive in the PC with a Windows 10 installation.

Everything on Ubuntu runs fine, until I open an app. Both Firefox and Browser consistently lockup the computer where mouse and keyboard are unresponsive.

I can access system settings and files without issue. The computer is connected to the internet and has updated since the new installation but I can't get it to stop crashing.

Ideally, I'm trying to get Teamviewer and Plex set up but so far I'm not having any luck.

Does anyone else have this issue or can point me in the direction to start troubleshooting?

I've since tried the Windows 10 installation and everything is working fine, so it would appear, to me anyway, at being a software/driver issue?

Any help much appreciated.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Could it be hardware acceleration?

Try firefox [safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode).

If firefox hangs, press CTRL-ALT-F1 and log in from console. Kill firefox (killall firefox, or killall -9 firefox). Log out and get back with CTRL-ALT-F7

Edit: (provided the computer is not too badly locked, of course)

Comment: WORKED :D i right clicked on the desktop to open console and typed /usr/bin/firefox -safe-mode

So what does this mean? Are there some settings I need to switch in Ubuntu so it runs stable?

Comment: It could mean there is a plugin causing problem, or Firefox is using your display driver in a manner that freezes it. You can try disabling FF hardware acceleration features from about:preferences#advanced -- and if that works, then probably the root cause is something related to display drivers. You could try to use different drivers. It can be a pain, but since you have a fresh installation, I suggest you try that. What display adapter you have, did you try to install manufacturer's best drivers? Or free drivers? Try the other option, if available.